# GSP page looks like not being interpreted by the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I have a grails application that after execute an action to load some datatable, I click on a link on the datatable that re-execute the same action and load the same page again - SO, when it load for the second time (after click on the link) looks like the browser didn´t process any javascript on my page - just ignore it.

The grails action is very simple, something like:

```
def index() {
        render (view: "page.gsp" ,model: [model])
    }
```

What could be happen?

**UPDATE**

Hi, moderators, please, close/delete this question because I found the solution and it is - basically - not related to grails but Javascript/Jquery istead. So, this question does not make sense. Thanks for you guys who tries to help me.

Comment: That's not how you render a view in Grails. Remove the `.gsp` extension. Also, if you specify the view itself instead of it name conventioned to the action, I believe you need `view: "/page"`.

Answer (score 1):

First thing browser never get's a **.gsp** page it will always get an html which can be interpreted by browser. There is a syntax problem please use below code

> render (view: "page" ,model: [model])

also check 
https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#gsp